# Explicit form of Noether current for Majorana equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem, majorana-fermions, grassmann-numbers

I am looking for an explicit form of the Noether current for the Majorana equation.

Comment: Why can't you work it out yourself?

Comment: Because I believe it is well known.

Comment: I'm not denying that, but what's stopping you from just calculating it yourself?

Comment: I prefer to have a reference.